# How to give 5 points if they are able to answer a question in one go but only 3 if they answer it on the second go in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Artist quiz")
question1 = "Who sang Perfect?"
options1 = "a.Myslef\nb. Papa\nc. Johhny\nd. Ed Sheeran\n"
print(question1)
print(options1)

while True:
    response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")    

if response == "d":
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect!!! Try again.")
    while True:
        response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")

        if response == "d":
            stop = True
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect!!! You ran out of your attempts")
            stop = True
            break
    if stop:
        break

question2 = "Who sang Umbrella?"
options2 = "a.Okie dokie\nb. Rhianna\nc. Shakira\nd. Beyonce\n"
print(question2)
print(options2)

while True:
    response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")

if response == "b":
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect!!! Try again.")

    while True:
        response = input("Hit 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd' for your answer\n")

        if response == "b":
            stop = True
            break
        else:print("Artist quiz")
```

This is what I have so far but I would like to add a scoring system where it is 5 points for answering it in one try but only 3 for answering it in 2 tries. Any help would be appreciated. I still need it to work for both questions.

Comment: track the number of incorrect answers. (counter) if you have more than 1 incorrect answer when the correct answer is givem, decrease the awarded points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track number of tries, I made a little more sophisticated solution where you can easily add a question. Also every question can have different amount of points or penalty in second try. I hope it will help

```
questions = {   
        1: {    'question': 'Who sang Perfect?', 'points': 5, 'penalty': 2,  
                'answers': {'a':'Myself', 'b': 'Papa', 'c': 'Johhny', 'd': 'Ed Sheeran'}, 'correct_answer': 'd'},
        2: {    'question': 'Who sang Umbrella?', 'points': 6, 'penalty': 2,  
                'answers': {'a':'Okie dokie', 'b': 'Rhianna', 'c': 'Shakira'}, 'correct_answer': 'b'}
    }

obtained_points = 0
max_tries = 2

print("Artist quiz")

# iterate through questions in dictionary
for key, value in questions.items():
    #print question
    print('Question number {}.\n'.format(key))
    print(value['question'])
    for k, answer in value['answers'].items():  
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, answer))

    points = value['points']
    current_try = 0

    while current_try < max_tries:
        # possible answers
        options = value['answers'].keys()

        hint = "\nHit {} for your answer\n".format(','.join("'" + option + "'" for option in options))
        response = input(hint)

        # does not count try if answer is not in options 
        if response not in options:
            print('Your answers is not in options')
            continue

        current_try += 1
        if response == value['correct_answer']:
            obtained_points += points if current_try == 0 else points - value['penalty']
            print("Nice!")
            break
        else:
            if current_try == max_tries:
                print('Your are out of tries')
            else:
                print("Incorrect!!! Try again.")

print('You obtained {} points!'.format(obtained_points))
```